# How can I animate a gradient layer which increases its width?

Tags: swift, animation

I'm using a simple `UIView` which I want to animate and I added a gradient layer to it.
I want to increase the width of the view and the layer placed on the view,
but all I get is that the view increases its width but not the layer.

Example: Let's say I have a `UIView` with `height = width = 50`
I animate it by setting the width to: `width += 50`. This animation is working. If I do the same with layer then noting happens. The layer does not increase its width. I tried some things to fix this (see comments in code) but nothing is working.

Here is my code

```
func performNextTitleAnimation() {

        let overlayViewHeight = overlayView.frame.size.height
        let overlayViewWidth = overlayView.frame.size.width
        let animationHeight: CGFloat = 48
        let overlayViewHalfHeight = (overlayViewHeight) / 2

        swipeAnimation = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: overlayViewHalfHeight - (animationHeight/2), width: 48, height: animationHeight))

        swipeAnimation.backgroundColor = .gray

        swipeAnimation.layer.cornerRadius = swipeAnimation.frame.size.height / 2

        gradientLayer.frame = swipeAnimation.bounds

        overlayView.addSubview(swipeAnimation)
        swipeAnimation.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
            self.gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 24

            self.swipeAnimation.frame.size.width += 50

            //Things I tried, but not working
            //1.) self.gradientLayer.frame.size.width += 50
            //2.) self.gradientLayer.frame.size.width = self.swipeAnimation.frame.size.width
            //3.) self.gradientLayer.bounds = self.swipeAnimation.bounds

        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

Gradient Layer

```
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, animationColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3*(CGFloat.pi) / 2, 0, 0, 1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best result I've ever achieved when I needed to animate `CAGrandientLayer`s size is to use it as a layerClass of a custom `UIView`:

```
class GrandientView: UIView {
  override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
    return CAGradientLayer.self
  }

  var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
    // it is safe to force cast here
    // since we told UIView to use this exact type
    return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // setup your gradient
  }
}
```